# USB Sound Card with no "native" sound card

Tags: linux, audio, sound-card, usb-audio

On a PC (HP ML110 G60), with no soundcard, Can I achieve sound/microphone plugging a USB [sound card](http://steelseries.com/products/audio/steelseries-siberia-usb-soundcard)? Runnning Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Can I achieve sound/microphone plugging a USB sound card?**

Yes but you must ensure that drivers are available for your chosen Operating System.

The link you gave says

> Operating systems: Win XP/Vista/Win 2000/Win 98/Win ME/Mac OS or a Sony Playstation 3

So the vendors of that specific device do not provide Linux drivers.

I'd [search the intertubes](http://www.google.com/search?q=usb+soundcard+linux) for one that does.

Comment: I've read about people about using that product for Linux. What about USB speakers, will they work out of the box?

Comment: @jacktrades: I'd expect USB speakers to work out of the box. This is because these usually conform to a standard USB device class. I'd still check (ask the vendor - that way you can return for a refund if they are not fit for the specific purpose for which they were expressly purchased)

Comment: that standard USB profile will it work even for Linux? So those USB speakers have a built in audio card....

Comment: @Jacktrades: USB speakers mostly don't contain audio circuitry to support all the features you'd expect of a sound card: microphone-input, host-based volume-mixing, etc. They are examples of powered-speakers (i.e. a bit like "monitors") rather than passive-speakers in that they contain an audio amplifier.

Comment: they should contain a simplified version of an audio card then, right? it's an audio card at the end of the day

Comment: @jacktrades: Nope. Cars and planes both have wheels, that doesn't mean a car is a plane at the end of the day. A USB speaker and a USB "sound-card" are both USB audio devices. I wouldn't take it further than that.